# Nifi to Ldap integration configution error

Tags: apache-nifi

I have Configured NIFI integration with ldap but am getting the following error :

[image]

[image]

Please help me solve it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: could you please provide the error stacktrace from the log file instead of screenshots and your nifi parameters related to LDAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that NiFi was unable to load the conf/login-identity-providers.xml file. Without seeing the file, I would assume that the configuration there has left the XML malformed.